# spacy installation deletes conda.exe - 'conda' is not recognized or corrupted

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda list
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I was installing a package using conda when it errored out. I think that the install application was trying to upgrade conda but could not. And so has deleted the conda.exe in the process. I do not see conda.exe anymore in my Anaconda3 folder. How do I get conda.exe. Do I need to reinstall Anaconda?

Comment: Simple answer - yes.

Comment: Conda package installation errors don't remove `conda.exe`, though

Comment: @cricket_007 yes the installation has removed it. That is what is surprising me. It was trying to upgrade the conda version I think.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't. If it does, then you shouldn't give the installer administrator privileges because it could delete anything else since you are in Program Files

Comment: @cricket_007 The problem is that if I dont give admin privileges it will not install as it needs to install / update other dependencies. Anyway, I think I will just go ahead and reinstall

Comment: You don't need to install Anaconda into Program Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cricket_007 thank you for the pointers

In the first try, was trying to install the package spacy on a base installation of Anaconda with Python 3.6. using the conda command with admin privileges and that is when conda.exe got deleted.

This time as reinstalled spacy without admin privileges and the same error came when it tried to install the dependency tdqm package but conda.exe did not get deleted. So I understood that there was an issue with the tdqm package which is one of the dependencies for spacy.

[image]

Then I installed tdqm separately from another source and it installed without any problems.

[image]

And then I installed spacy again then spacy and all the dependency packages got installed properly.
[image]

Everything installed successfully.

Learnings:

1. Anaconda should not be installed in the Program files directory as
   then you would need admin privileges to install any package.
2. Always install packages without admin privileges
3. Keep a check on the dependencies